# How to unselect (blank) in .AutoFilter?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is how to select only blank values in column 1 :

```
.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="(blank)"
```

How to `unselect` those blanks  . How to select anything but blank

`.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria:<>"(blank)"`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
```

You could try recording macro while manually doing the filter.